# Complex matrix with a single Eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Im not sure about a question, and need your help.

Is a complex matrix with a single Eigenvalue necessarily diagonalizable?

I'm thinking that the answer is true because the opposite case does happen : There is a  diagonalizable matrix with only one eigenvalue, but I dont know how to prove it.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its number of eigenvectors is the same as its dimension. So I this the answer is no. And you can regard real matrix as complex matrix.

Comment: The answer is no indeed, since $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ only has the eigenvalue $1$, but is clearly not similar to $I_2$.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

is real, thus complex, has a single eigenvalue, and is not diagonalizable.